# Excel/VBA Basic Function Problem

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is a total noob question, but can anyone tell me why this function always returns 0:

```
Function Cd(Re As Double)

Select Case Re

    Case Re < 1
        Cd = 24 / Re
    Case 1 < Re < 1000
        Cd = 18 * Re ^ (-0.6)
    Case 1000 < Re
        Cd = 0.44

End Select

End Function
```

Whenever I call it in the spreadsheet, it always returns 0. For example Cd(5000) = 0, when it should be 0.44. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5):

```
Case Re < 1
```

That is not good. You evaluate `Re` in your `Select Case` in the first place, and now you are comparing `Re` to `Re < 1`. Obviously, you wanted

```
Case Is < 1
```

---

```
Case 1 < Re < 1000
```

That is not good either. There is no `< X <` operator in VB. This expression evaluates to `(1 < (Re < 1000))`, which essentially becomes either `1 < False` or `1 < True`, which is always `False`. What you meant to write here is:

```
Case 1 to 1000
```

---

```
Case 1000 < Re
```

Same problem again. You obviously meant:

```
Case Is > 1000
```

Comment: Hey Brian, if this answer is correct, don't forget to press the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the things GSerg mentions I think you should also explicitly cast the function to return a double.

I just tested that this works as you expect:

```
Function Cd(Re As Double) As Double

  Select Case Re

    Case Is < 1
        Cd = 24 / Re
    Case 1 To 1000
        Cd = 18 * Re ^ (-0.6)
    Case Is > 1000
        Cd = 0.44

  End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple change (other than the '< x <' ). Make it

```
Select Case True
```